# Python read file into list - edit

Tags: python

- edit - It seems that I have made an error with the calculation of number of parts tested:

  `lines = len(file.readlines())`
  `N = lines - 2`

It did work when i tested it in a separate script though...

Beginner here in need of help. I have a problem with my python script which I haven't been able to work out by myself. The script is supposed to read floating point from a text file and do some calculations. I can't get the numbers into the list `R[]`.

Below is a sample of the text file where the first line (`s[0]`) is the nominal value, line two (`s[1]`) is the tolerance and the following lines are some resistors.

---

3300.0

10.0

3132.0

3348.5

3557.3

3467.4

3212.0

3084.6

3324.0

I have the following code:

```
R = []
Ntoolow = Nlow = Nhigh = Ntoohigh = 0.0
lines = 0

def find_mean(q):
    tot = 0.0
    c = len(q)
    for x in range (c):
        tot += q[x]
        return tot/c


def find_median(q):
    c = len(q)
    if c%2:
        return float(q[int(c/2)])
    else:
        c /= 2
        return (q[int(c)]+q[int(c-1)])/2.0


file_name = input("Please enter the file name: ")
file = open(file_name, "r")

s = file.readlines()

Rnom = float(s[0])
Tol = float(s[1])


keepgoing = True

while keepgoing:
    s = file.readline()
    if s == "":
        keepgoing = False
    else:
        R.append(float(s))


lines = len(file.readlines())
N = lines - 2
R.sort()


Rmin = R[0]
Rmax = R[N-1]

Rlowerlimit = Rnom - Tol
Rupperlimit = Rnom + Tol


for rn in R:
    if rn < Rlowerlimit:
        Ntoolow += 1
    elif rn < Rnom:
        Nlow += 1
    elif rn <= Rupperlimit:
        Nhigh += 1
    else:
        Ntoohigh += 1


Ptoolow = 100.0 * Ntoolow / N
Plow = 100.0 * Nlow / N
Phigh = 100.0 * Nhigh / N
Ptoohigh = 100.0 * Ntoohigh / N


Rmean = find_mean(R)
Rmedian = find_median(R)


print("Total number of parts tested: " + str(N))
print("The largest resistor is: " + str(Rmax) + " and the smallest is: " + str(Rmin))
print("The mean is: " + str(Rmean) + " and the median is: " + str(Rmedian))
print("The percentage of resistors that have too low tolerance is: " + str(Ptoolow) + "%")
print("The percentage of resistors that have low tolerance is: " + str(Plow) + "%")
print("The percentage of resistors that have high tolerance is: " + str(Phigh) + "%")
print("The percentage of resistors that have too high tolerance is: " + str(Ptoohigh) + "%")

file.close()
```

Comment: cant get your question... do u want to add return digit into list R[] ?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Do you get an error – if so, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code ,

```
while keepgoing:
     s = file.readline()
     if s == "":
         keepgoing = False
     else:
         R.append(float(s))
```

with,

```
for i in s:
    R.append(float(i))
```

Its giving me the answer...

Here is the output after I Edited your code,

```
Total number of parts tested: -2
The largest resistor is: 3348.5 and the smallest is: 10.0
The mean is: 1.11111111111 and the median is: 3300.0
The percentage of resistors that have too low tolerance is: -200.0%
The percentage of resistors that have low tolerance is: -0.0%
The percentage of resistors that have high tolerance is: -50.0%
The percentage of resistors that have too high tolerance is: -200.0%
```

Comment: How do I keep it from adding the first two numbers (3300.0 and 10.0) into the list?

Comment: you dont want to add first two numbers? (3300.0and 10.0) ?

Comment: if you want to keep it way from adding first two digit (3300.0 and 10.0) means  you should start your text file from 2nd element  like this,  for i in s[2:]:

Comment: answer was accepted by the user. then who make it negative?

Answer (score 1):

Python has a number of libraries that can read information from CSV files, such as csv, numpy and pandas. Try the following:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```

You can then iterate over the rows like this:

```
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip the empty lines and remove line breaks `\n` with [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip):

```
filename = 'test.dat'

with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
    s = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in f if line.rstrip()]

print(s)
#[3300.0, 10.0, 3132.0, 3348.5, 3557.3, 3467.4, 3212.0, 3084.6, 3324.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel, Python knows when it's reached the end of a file, you don't need to add your own clause (plus, won't detecting for "" possibly end on empty lines? Not too sure).

Try this code:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
   try: 
       R = float(f.readlines())
   except TypeError:
       pass
```

Comment: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Comment: ^ catch these as follows

    `with open(file_name) as f:
    try:
       R = float(f.readlines())
    except TypeError:
       pass`

Comment: Thanks guys, changed it